# Can I use Core Data as a replacement for User Defaults?

Tags: swift, core-data, userdefaults

I've programmed a few apps using swift where I saved properties using user defaults and the code gets a little long as I start to user more variables. I'm now working on an app with a player class that has 6 properties and there are 100 players, so rather than write 600 save and 600 load lines for user default I wanted to try to use CoreData and SQLite to persist the data.

I started by creating a smaller proof of concept app to make sure that I can save and load player.name and player.attack for 2 players to keep it simple and I'm having trouble. I've tried the following:

[image: main View Controller]

My example code is as follows for the main view controller

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import GameplayKit

var player = Character(context: CoreDataStack.context)
var monster = Character(context: CoreDataStack.context)

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var statsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerAttackButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerHealthButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var montserAttackButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var monsterNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var monsterHealthButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchData()

        if player.name == nil {player.name = ""}
        if monster.name == nil {monster.name = ""}

        updateStatsLabel()

        // Dismiss keyboard on return when typing character name
        //Looks for single or multiple taps.
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))

        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        self.playerNameField.delegate = self
        self.monsterNameField.delegate = self

    }

    // MARK: Fetching Data
    func fetchData() -> Void {

        let moc = CoreDataStack.context
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Character")

        do {
            let fetchedPerson = try moc.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Character]

            print(fetchedPerson.count)
            for object in fetchedPerson {
player.name = object.name
                print(object.name!)
            }

        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch characters: \(error)")
        }

    }



    // MARK: Delete Data Records

    func deleteRecords() -> Void {
        let moc = CoreDataStack.context
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Character")

        let result = try? moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
        let resultData = result as! [Character]

        for object in resultData {
            moc.delete(object)
        }

        do {
            try moc.save()
            print("saved!")
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        } catch {

        }

    }

    // MARK: Update Data
    func updateRecords() -> Void {
        let moc = CoreDataStack.context

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Character")

        let result = try? moc.fetch(fetchRequest)

        let resultData = result as! [Character]
        for object in resultData {
            object.name! = player.name!
            print(object.name!)
        }
        do{
            try moc.save()
            print("saved")
        }catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }


    }


    @IBAction func deleteButton(_ sender: Any) {
        deleteRecords()
    }
    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        fetchData()
        updateRecords()
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        player.name = playerNameField.text!
        monster.name = monsterNameField.text!
        updateStatsLabel()
        //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }

    @IBAction func playerRollAttackButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let random = GKRandomSource()
        let roll = GKGaussianDistribution(randomSource: random, lowestValue: 1, highestValue: 20)
        player.attack = Int64(roll.nextInt())
        updateStatsLabel()
    }

    @IBAction func playerRollHealth(_ sender: Any) {
        let random = GKRandomSource()
        let roll = GKGaussianDistribution(randomSource: random, lowestValue: 1, highestValue: 8)
        player.health = Int64(roll.nextInt())
        updateStatsLabel()
    }

    @IBAction func monsterRollAttackButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let random = GKRandomSource()
        let roll = GKGaussianDistribution(randomSource: random, lowestValue: 1, highestValue: 12)
        monster.attack = Int64(roll.nextInt())
        updateStatsLabel()
    }

    @IBAction func monsterRollHealth(_ sender: Any) {
        let random = GKRandomSource()
        let roll = GKGaussianDistribution(randomSource: random, lowestValue: 1, highestValue: 20)
        monster.health = Int64(roll.nextInt())
        updateStatsLabel()
    }

    func updateStatsLabel() {
        statsLabel.text = "\(player.name!) health: \(player.health)\n\n\(player.name!)'s attack: \(player.attack)\n\n\(monster.name!) health: \(monster.health)\n\n\(monster.name!)'s attack: \(monster.attack)"
    }

}
```

And for the CoreDataStack view controller:

```
import CoreData

class CoreDataStack {

    static let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreDataSample")
        container.loadPersistentStores { (_, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
        return container
    }()

    static var context: NSManagedObjectContext { return persistentContainer.viewContext }

    class func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext

        guard context.hasChanges else {
            return
        }

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping I'd be able to assign a name to the player and to the monster that are held in the player.name and monster.name variables, save them using CoreData and then load them back into the variables when the app opens next (and the same for other variables). Changing the names would result in an overwrite in the CoreData model such that the old data is lost and is replaced by the new data. I'm having the following difficulties:

- Saving seems to be resulting in multiple records being created, but not each time I save, only each time I close and open the app.
- When I first open the app the correct saved data isn't loaded into the view, which I think I can fix by modifying the "player.name = object.name" to sort the object first, which I haven't been able to test yet since I'm having trouble with the item above.
- Deleting records produces the following error:
  CoreDataSample[5879:362306] 
  CoreData: error: Mutating a managed object 0xd0000000005c0000  (0x604000290310) after it has been removed from its context.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for reviewing my question :)

Comment: FYI UserDefaults is made to store preferences, nothing more